# Comparing 2 Similar Types?

Tags: haskell

I have 2 types, Tree and BinTree. The way I implement compare is like so:

```
instance (Eq a) => Ord (Tree a) where
  t <= u = traces t `subseteq` traces u

instance (Eq a) => Eq (Tree a) where
  t == u = traces t `subseteq` traces u && traces u `subseteq` traces t

instance (Eq a) => Ord (BinTree a) where
  t <= u = traces t `subseteq` traces u

instance (Eq a) => Eq (BinTree a) where
  t == u = traces t `subseteq` traces u && traces u `subseteq` traces t
```

As you can see, my traces function is happy to operate on both Tree and BinTree, thus there should be a way for me to do:
myBinTree < myTree

Thus comparing a BinTree to a Tree

How does one go about implementing this so that BinTrees and Trees can be compared, since a BinTree is a subset of a Tree.

Comment: You can [convert the `BinTree` to a `Tree`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511329/converting-a-binarytree-to-a-tree) and compare the `Tree`s.

Comment: @Cirdec Yes, but is there a way to do that in a way where I can use the '<' operator?

Comment: No, [`<` has the type `Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-60-). The two arguments must be the same type.

Comment: How does haskell compare floats to integers?

Comment: Haskell doesn't compare floats to integers. When you write `1.7 < 3` the real types are `1.7 :: Fractional a => a` and `3 :: Num a => a`. Haskell has [built in defaults for dealing with number types](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#default-decls), and will decide that `a` is `Double` (by default it tries `Integer` then `Double` then gives up). If we explicitly write `1.7 < (3 :: Integer)` we get a type error; Haskell can not compare the `Double` `1.7` to an `Integer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in such way that it becomes an instance of the [`Eq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq) or [`Ord`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord) classes. These classes have the signature:

```
(==) :: a -> a -> Bool
(/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

and so on...

You could write your own `(==)` function, but then that function becomes ambiguous, and as a result you will always need to specify about which `(==)` operator you are actually talking.

The answer to your comment "*How does haskell compare floats to integers?*" is that it doesn't. If you write:

```
> (1 :: Int) == (1.0 :: Float)

<interactive>:56:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Float'
    In the second argument of `(==)', namely `(1.0 :: Float)'
    In the expression: (1 :: Int) == (1.0 :: Float)
    In an equation for `it': it = (1 :: Int) == (1.0 :: Float)
```

You see that the comparison can't be done. You can do this by converting:

```
> fromIntegral (1 :: Int) == (1.0 :: Float)
True
```

Where `fromIntegral` is a function that converts the `Int` into - in this case - a `Float`. You can do the same by implementing a `bin2tree` function.

You can of course define your own similar class:

```
class Similar a b where
    (=~) :: a -> b -> Bool
    (/=~) :: a -> b -> Bool
    (/=~) x y = not $ x =~ y
```

(and add `{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}` in the file as modifier).

And then for instance:

```
instance (Similar a b) => Similar [a] [b] where
    (=~) [] [] = True
    (=~) _  [] = False
    (=~) [] _  = True
    (=~) (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x =~ y) && (xs =~ ys)
```

But the problem is that you will have to redefine a lot of methods yourself (that take use of `Eq` like `nub`) such that they work with your `Similar` class.